# Doubly linked list no longer linked in both directions

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I'm having some issues with a section of code I'm writing and was hoping someone may be able to help me see where I've gone wrong and explain why so I can better understand it.

I'm being told that my doubly linked list is no longer linked in both directions but I'm failing to see where I've gone wrong. I'll include the problematic section of code below:

```
public void deleteWithValue(int searchValue)
{
    // Delete the first node in the list with the given value.
    if (head.data == searchValue)
    {
        head = head.next;
        return;
    }
    DoublyLinkedListNode current = head;
    DoublyLinkedListNode prev = current;
    while (current.next != null)
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
        if (current.data == searchValue)
        {
            prev = current.next;
            current = current.next;
            current.prev = prev;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks,

Jess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the condition `current.data == searchValue` evaluates to `true`, then you need to update the `prev` link for the next node, as well as the `next` link for the previous node order to maintain links in both directions.

As it stands, you're not updating the link for `current.prev.next`, so you're losing the link in that direction.

Also, the way you're treating the `head` node as a special case means that `current.next.prev` doesn't get updated if the `head` happens to be the node to remove.

Consider this instead:

```
public void deleteWithValue(int searchValue) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        // If true, then the current node is the one to remove
        if (current.data == searchValue) {  

            if (current == head) {
                head = head.next;
            }

            // Ensure the previous node maintains a link to the next node
            if (current.prev != null) {
                current.prev.next = current.next;
            }

            // Ensure the next node maintains a link to the previous node   
            if (current.next != null) {
                current.next.prev = current.prev;
            }

            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ben Cottrell. That was a nice easy explanation that anyone could understand! I've modified my code having read your reply and also @selbie reply too and it seems to have done the job!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues:

John3130 started to type out this issue:

```
if (head.data == searchValue)
{
    head = head.next;
    return;
}
```

In the above case, you forget to set head.prev to null.

```
if (head.data == searchValue)
{
    head = head.next;
    if (head != null) {
        head.prev null;
    }
    return;
}
```

The other issue is if your delete method is called when `head` is null.  (Assuming `head==null` implies an empty list.)  It will throw an exception when attempting to deference head.data.

You actually don't need the "prev" value at all.  Just do judicious checking of null after you search from the start:

```
public void deleteWithValue(int searchValue) {

    DoublyLinkedListNode current = head;
    // search
    while ((current != null) && (current.data != searchValue)) {
        current = current.next;   
    }

    if (current != null)  {

        if (current.next != null)  {
           current.next.prev = current.prev;
        }

        if (current.prev != null) {
            current.prev.next = current.next;
        }

        if (current == head) {
            head = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you selbie. Between looking at your comment and @Ben Cottrell I've managed to get it working happily!
Thank you!
ps. both replies were equally helpful but I could only mark one as being the most helpful so I've marked Ben Cottrell's as it was the easiest to understand.

Comment: You can only accept one answer, but you can upvote as many answers as you Iike.

Comment: I've upvoted both answers but because my reputation is below 5 it's recorded it but not displaying it apparently!